# Почему возникает ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

При выполнении функции name почему-то вылазит ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Из-за чего это?

```
import nl_international as db_nl_international; from 
nl_international import Database
import asyncio
async def name_nl_international(name_search):
  database = await Database.ConnectDatabase()
  result = await asyncio.gather(Database.name(database, 
name_search))
  return result
```

---

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import aiosqlite
from sqlite3 import Error

class Database():
  async def ConnectDatabase(**kwargs):
    try:
      db = await aiosqlite.connect('nl_international.db', check_same_thread=False)
      c = await db.cursor()
    except Error:
      print(f'Database: {Error}')

  async def name(db, name_search):
    c = await db.cursor()
    result = await c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM clients WHERE name == '{name_search}'").fetchall()
    await db.commit()
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция класса Database ConnectDatabase не возвращает значения, следовательно по умолчанию возвращается значение None. То есть в этой строке `database = await Database.ConnectDatabase()` database равняется None. Далее идёт вызов метода name класса Database с переменной database, которая равна None, но в методе исспользуется как объект базы данных. Исправляется добавлением `return db` в метод ConnectDatabase.